# Lag in collision detection

Tags: collision-detection, sprites, pygame, lag

I am a beginner with PyGame and am currently making a simple game using but I am having difficulty with the collision detection. When the game runs, the response to the collision detection (printing the score and removing the sprite) is very slow. The two responses occur at the same time but much later than when the sprites actually collide. I was wondering how I could change my code to fix this?

My code is here: http://pastebin.com/9t2hcAxH and I think the issue is in the game loop at the bottom.

Comment: Can you somehow provide a download link to the exe so that I can run it and see what's the problem that's happening in your game ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't try your code because I don't have the images, but I do see some problems:

When you spawn your sprites, for example:

```
elif event.type == ADDMET:
    asteroid = Meteor(720, random.randint(50, 300))
    asters.add(asteroid)
    astss = True
```

This creates an asteroid and adds it to the sprite group "asters".  This is fine, but each time the event triggers, you spawn another asteroid and assign it to the variable "asteroid".  This is going to cause a problem later:

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(cat, asters, True):
        asters.remove(asteroid)
        life -= 1
        print(str(life))
        if life == 0:
            running = False
            break
```

The spritecollide function checks "cat" vs. the sprite group "asters".  Any asteroids that collide with cat are removed from the group (because of the 'True' flag).  spritecollide returns a list of these asteroids.

However, you're not using that list, you're just saying to remove "asteroid" from the group - but that may not be the asteroid that collided with cat!  "asteroid" is going to be equal to the last asteroid you spawned.  This problem is occurring with all your collision checks.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(cat, asters, True)
for hit in hits:
        # don't need this, the "True" takes care of it
        # asters.remove(asteroid) 
        life -= 1
        print(str(life))
        if life == 0:
            running = False
            break
```